# jquery and jquery-ui not working in Springsource Tool Suite 2.3.3.M1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I installed the jquery and jquery-ui plugins for grails into SpringSource Tool Suite (STS-Eclipse) following the documentation located at http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery and using the grails command-line tool included with STS-Eclipse as follows:

grails> install-plugin jquery
grails> install-plugin jquery-ui

According to the documentation, both jquery and jquery-ui should appear in my projects web-app/js directory which is located under my eclipse workspace as follows:

workspace-sts-2.3.3.M1//web-app/js

Instead, both items are installed in ~/.grails/1.3.3/projects//plugins/ and are never copied to my web-app/js directory.

Needless to say my GSP views can't find the jquery files. I will likely copy the files manually; however, it seems to go against the convention of using grails install-plugin jquery.

Has anyone else had a similar problem? Is there a configuration parameter I should set?

Thx,
Ashley

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-Grails-1-3-2-Jquery-1-4-2-2-and-g-javascript-tag-td2271796.html.

I have to add plugin="jquery" to my g:javascript tag like .

Thanks
Ashley